# Can I develop a Dashboard Report for Data Allocated vs Max Storage for my Azure Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure, monitoring, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have an Azure SQL Server Database - Managed Instance I'd like to monitor. Here is the widget that Azure shows me on the database summary page. I'd like to put this widget, or at least the information which this widget exposes, on my comprehensive monitoring dashboard.

[image]

The problem is, I don't see any metric for Max Storage. Space Used vs Allocated is useless to me since Azure allocates space just-in-time as it is needed. The question I need to keep on top of is where do I stand with space used vs max storage. Is this possible?

[image]

Just so you don't have to take my word for it - here is a screenshot scrolled down to where M... would be. As you can see there is no entry for Max Storage.

[image]

Comment: "*Azure allocates space just-in-time as it is needed*" - Wouldn't that imply there is no max storage, or am I missing something?

Comment: The full spec is - Azure allocates space just-in-time as it is needed until the Max Storage is reached. i.e. Max Storage isn't a technical limitation, it's more of a billing and accounting protection which safeguards my processing from mistakenly accumulating more space than I am willing to pay for. So we keep this in place to assure that our data accumulation proceeds at a reasonable pace and from time to time I adjust this. That's the purpose of the pie chart on the summary page and I'm looking for a way to display this prominently on my dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‘Data space used percent’ metric can be useful for monitoring database storage consumption.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Interesting that this metric is relative to the Max Storage metric, but Max Storage itself isn't available as a metric.